# Plotting two random numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot two random numpy array but I'm not geeting line. Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Decalring numpy array variable
a = np.random.randint(2, 10, size=(1, 10))
b = np.random.randint(5, 15, size=(1, 10))

# plotting
plt.title("Line graph")
plt.xlabel("X axis")
plt.ylabel("Y axis")
plt.plot(a, b, color ="green", label="Sample Line", marker="*")
plt.show()
```

Can anyone Explain me why its not printing line and show correct code?

Comment: Replace `size=(1, 10)` with `size=(10, )` and also I hope you realize that you are plotting `a` as X and `b` as Y, and not plotting `a` and `b` as Y with one point per index (and thus `range(10)` as X).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the shapes of **a** and **b**, you'll find they both have a shape of (1, 10).

```
a = np.random.randint(2, 10, size=(1, 10))
b = np.random.randint(5, 15, size=(1, 10))
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)
```

Matplotlib sees this as many "lines", each "line" with just one point! What you want is a single line with 10 points, so **a** and **b** should have a shape of (10,) instead.

The following code the above issue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Decalring numpy array variable
a = np.random.randint(2, 10, 10)
b = np.random.randint(5, 15, 10)

# plotting
plt.title("Line graph")
plt.xlabel("X axis")
plt.ylabel("Y axis")
plt.plot(a, b, color ="green", label="Sample Line", marker="*")
plt.show()
```

But the result is as follows:

[image]

Here we have plotted **a** as the coordinates of points on the x-axis, and **b** as the coordinates of the line on the y-axis. Perhaps you wanted two lines that are continuous along the x-axis? If so, the following code will solve this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Decalring numpy array variable
a = np.random.randint(2, 10, 10)
b = np.random.randint(5, 15, 10)
xAxis = np.arange(10)

# plotting
plt.title("Line graph")
plt.xlabel("X axis")
plt.ylabel("Y axis")
plt.plot(xAxis, a, color ="red", label="Sample Line", marker="*")
plt.plot(xAxis, b, color ="blue", label="Sample Line", marker="*")
plt.show()
```

[image]